# Building Mavenized jCuda with maven

Tags: maven, nexus, jcuda

Well I have installed **Nvidia** driver and **cuda 7** successfully and already built and run many **jcuda** (not mavenized) projects in *eclipse*.

But I wanted to migrate to the mavenized version one. 
So, I cloned [this](https://github.com/MysterionRise/mavenized-jcuda) repository and tried to build it. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and I have set up **nexus**, too. But when I want to build it with
`mvn clean package` I got this:

`Downloading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/jcuda/jcublas/0.7.0a/jcublas-0.7.0a.pom
[WARNING] The POM for jcuda:jcublas:jar:0.7.0a is missing, no dependency information available`

for all of the *.*poms*

and after these warnings, the build get finished unsuccessfully with:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project org.mystic:mavenized-
jcuda:jar:0.1.2: The following artifacts could not be resolved:  jcuda:jcublas:jar:0.7.0a, jcuda:jcuda:jar:0.7.0a ...`

and it lists all of the jcuda *.*jars* and *.*sos*

Have I forgotten something?

**UPDATE**:

I used option `-Dmaven.repo.local=repo` with `mvn clean package` and every thing is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm 80% sure, that this is because of your local **Nexus**

*Failure to find jcuda:jcublas:jar:0.7.0a in http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are force* (**taken from your log file**)

Could you turn it off? It should resolve the issue.

P.S. Current situation with mavenized-jcuda project is, that it takes artifacts from local repo, since this artifacts are not presented in Maven Central or other hosted repositories.

Answer (score 0):

It was *nexus* problem. And I figured it out in a better way than turn it off.

In the maven `settings.xml` (~/.m2/settings.xml) the mirrorOf pattern of `*` causes any repository request to be redirected to this mirror and to my single repository group. Another option is `external:*` which matches all repositories except those using localhost or file based repositories.

Putting `external:*` instead of `*` solved my problem.